# How to get rid of ONLY ONE mob permanently in minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I want to get rid of only ONE mob, not ALL mobs, because this one mob in minecraft is extrmely annoying. How would I got about doing that? A mod or something?

Comment: Which mob? There are more than a few.

Answer (score 2):

Kill of all of this type of mob by running this command on a clock:

```
/tp @e[type=<Type Of Mob>] ~ ~-600 ~
```

Notice that /tp -600 is used instead of /kill to remove the dying animation and drops.

Comment: Op is seeking a permanent solution. This isn't one.

Comment: @ydobonebi this is as permanent as can be done without mods (note the clock part!). Mod recommendations OTOH are off-topic.